# Ignite: a simple group by sql query costs about 40s with 20 million pieces of data

Tags: sql, ignite

## prepare

- 16 core 32 G
- Ignite server version 2.7.5
- sqlline version 1.3.0
- jdk 1.8
- data file: csv formate;size 3G,10millon peice
- data region 15G

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
    <!-- Redefining the default region's settings -->
    <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
        <property name="maxSize" value="#{15L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</property>
```

## load data

1. create table 'test'
2. load data from data.csv into table test

## execute sql

```
SELECT division_code            AS division_code,
       sum(num)                 AS num,
       sum(amount)              AS amount
FROM test
GROUP BY division_code
```

it costs 47.089 seconds

then add index on division_code field

`CREATE INDEX division_code ON test (division_code);`

it costs 47.844 seconds

use explan

```
SELECT
    A__Z0.DIVISION_CODE AS __C0_0,
    SUM(A__Z0.NUM) AS __C0_1,
    SUM(A__Z0.AMOUNT) AS __C0_2
FROM PUBLIC.TEST A__Z0
    /* PUBLIC.IDX_DIVISION_CODE */
GROUP BY A__Z0.DIVISION_CODE
/* group sorted */

SELECT
    __C0_0 AS DIVISION_CODE,
    CAST(CAST(SUM(__C0_1) AS DOUBLE) AS DOUBLE) AS NUM,
    CAST(CAST(SUM(__C0_2) AS DOUBLE) AS DOUBLE) AS AMOUNT
FROM PUBLIC.__T0
    /* PUBLIC."merge_scan" */
GROUP BY __C0_0
```

using gcviewer parse the gc.log :

when execute preceding group by sql ,total pause is 0.2s, never have full gc

Has anyone done ignite performance testing, should i turn on some switch? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: How unique is division_code? How many rows does the query return?

Comment: total 13 rows , the Individuality is not strong

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use scan query/partition affinity runs for such aggregation instead of SQL. SQL is going to hold a lot of data in heap for such operations. Ignite only has rudimentary optimizations for such cases (huge GROUP BY or ORDER BY).

What query do you mean as "pre group by sql"?

Comment: sorry, it means preceding. 
this sql :
SELECT division_code            AS division_code,
       sum(num)                 AS num,
       sum(amount)              AS amount
FROM test
GROUP BY division_code

Comment: I think this is the expected result. However, if you have a reproducer project which populates cache and then uses this query, I could try to profile its performance.